# TestNG annotated superclass in a different package

Tags: testng

I have a superclass and a subclass in different packages. The superclass has `@BeforeClass` and `@BeforeMethod` annotations.

However, these methods never get called. If I move both classes to a common package then both `@Before_xx` methods get called just fine.

Super class:

```
package com.blah.focus.test.integration;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class BookSuper {

@BeforeClass(groups = "unit")
void prepareDataSet() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside prepareDataSet");        
}

/**
 * 
 * @throws Exception
 */
@BeforeMethod(groups = "unit")
void beforeTestMethod() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Insde beforeTestMethod yy");

}
}
```

Sub class:

```
package com.blah.focus.domain;

public class BookTest extends BookSuper{
private Book book;

@Test(groups = "unit")
public void testGoodBookConstruction() {
    book = new Book();
    book.setAuthor("Henry");
    book.setTitle("Good Title");
    book.setPublished(new Date());
    book.setPublisher("Rodale");
}
}
```

Is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it should work, and it does work for me:

```
Inside prepareDataSet
Insde beforeTestMethod yy

===============================================
SingleSuite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

You are probably omitting some information.

Comment: First of all, it's a real honor to get a reply from the likes of Cedric Beust. Thank you. And yes, I was making a (terribly) silly mistake. Won't even explain. :-)